# How to access variables dynamically by building a string

Tags: javascript, variables

Looking to achieve something like this:

```
number = "first";
number2 = "second";

var firstColor = "red";
var secondColor = "blue";

//Changes background to red:
div.style.backgroundColor = number+"Color";

//Changes background to blue:
div.style.backgroundColor = number2+"Color";
```

When I try this it doesn't not work for me and the styles are not applied.
How can I do this dynamically.

Edit:

I have a series of else ifs to pick font text depending on which team is selected.
I want to create the variables like this:

```
 liverpoolColor = "red";

else if(team == "liverpool"){
        for (var x = 0; x < areas.length; x++){
//Then change the color dynamically like this:

            areas[x].style.color = team+"Color";
            }

        }
```

That way I can remove the else ifs completely and clean up my code:

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Are you sure `div` is an HTML element?

Comment: The above code is just a reference to what Im trying to do. See edit, to see my actual code

Comment: I don't know why people are down voting the answers. They have been very helpful & I will up-vote. The eval function worked perfect.

Comment: Kyle and I gave you answers that does the same without the need of evals (a.k.a : evil)

Comment: Yes I then adapted for an assoc array, but the eval function eliminated a lot of code in other areas. The joys of precedural eh?

Comment: @AnonOmus There is pretty much no circumstance where `eval` is the right way to go. The answers have downvotes because they are promoting bad practice as a quick fix solution to the problem. Your question is downvoted because this is a common problem that has been solved countless times on StackOverflow, including in the question I've linked to above.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

JavaScript [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function can help with that...

```
//Changes background to red:
div.style.backgroundColor = eval(number+"Color");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a object like this:

```
var colors = {
    firstColor: "red",
    secondColor: "blue"
};

div.style.backgroundColor = colors[number+"Color"];
```

Comment: Not sure why this got rated down... its basically the same answer as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript AND it doesn't use eval... please don't use eval.

Answer (score 1):

User ***eval*** method like this:

```
//Changes background to red:
div.style.backgroundColor = eval(number+"Color");

//Changes background to blue:
div.style.backgroundColor = eval(number2+"Color");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this ?

```
$('div').css('background-color', firstColor);
```

**EDIT**

Then you need this :

```
var colors = {
    'first' = 'red',
    'second' = 'blue'
}

var myColor = colors['first'];
```

Comment: OP didn't mention JQuery anywhere. This won't work if he does'nt have JQuery loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var colors = {
    "liverpool":"red",
    "barcelona":"green"
};

// Assume you have team = "liverpool"
div.style.backgroundColor = colors[team];
```

So depending on the team, the color will be applied.